# New Activity Button Not Visible in Android Studio 2023.2.1 (Iguana)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hi Stack Overflow community,

I'm encountering an issue in Android Studio 2023.2.1 (Iguana) where the "New Activity" button is not showing up. I've attached an image for reference.
[image: BUTTON NOT SHOWING]

I've tried restarting Android Studio and even reinstalling it, but the problem persists. Has anyone else experienced this issue or knows how to resolve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You did not tell how you came to the left menu to begin with.

Comment: @blackapps , i have just right clicked at java folder then got this

Comment: You should not click on java. Click on the package in it as there belong your Java files.

Comment: Please attach screen captures rather than pictures of a screen taken with a secondary device.